# Populate data to table from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I am using jQuery mobile and I have a table and want to populate data from database like a gridview, and perform edit delete operations from the database. I want to use JSON. Please give me the idea of how to bind the data from database.

Comment: You got a book at all, there fella?

Comment: have you tried this: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/bind-data-to-gridview-with-jquery-or.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jTemplates and Json for displaying and updating data.
Here is a good example for displaying data using jquery and jtemplate
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=573